# Can't manage to fetch data from a second JSON file

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a fetched data from a JSON file to make another fetch on a second screen.

Let's say I have a JSON file that was fetched via [www.fruits.com/data](http://www.fruits.com/data). Then one of the fruits has an ID of 1. In order to have more information about this fruit, I have to access another JSON file on [www.fruits.com/data/1](http://www.fruits.com/data/1).

I have both of these fetch functions to access JSON and drag said data:

```
List<Fruitmodel> parseFruit(String responseBody) {
  var list = json.decode(responseBody) as List<dynamic>;
  List<Fruitmodel> fruits = list.map((model) => Fruitmodel.fromJson(model)).toList();
  return fruits;
}


List<FruitDetails> parseDetails(String responseBody) {
  var list = json.decode(responseBody) as List<dynamic>;
  List<FruitDetails> fruit_details = list.map((model) => FruitDetails.fromJson(model)).toList();
  return fruit_details;
}
```

```
Future<List<FruitModel>> fetchFruit() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://fruits.com/data'));
    
  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    return compute(parseFruits, response.body);
  }
  else{
    throw Exception('Failed to get fruits.');
  }
}

Future<List<FruitDetails>> fetchDetails(int? a) async {      //"int a" is to get the fruit's ID
  String newUrl = 'https://fruits.com/data/' + a.toString();
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(newUrl));
    
  if (response.statusCode == 200){
    return compute(parseDetails, response.body);
  }
  else{
    throw Exception('Failed to get details.');
  }
}
```

On my homepage, I used the first fetch function (FetchFruit), and managed to make a fruit list with the first JSON file by using Future Builder (snapshots), then my next task is to click on a fruit and show its details.

```
...
onTap:(){
  Navigator.push(context,
  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)
  => DetailsPage(snapshot.data[index])));
...
```

So, on my next page, I'm initializing it with data from the fruit I've chosen. Then, I try to make the other fetch function (fetchDetails) by using said fruit's ID contained on the other JSON.

```
...
body: Center(
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: fetchDetails(this.fruit.id),    //Using ID to mount the correct URL
...
```

But... It doesn't work. I did a condition to tell me that if the snapshot has an error, it prints "Data not available" on the screen, and it does that instead of reading the second JSON file. What should I do for the second fetch to be done correctly?

In resume:
1st JSON file -> ID -> used to access 2nd JSON file -> not working

Comment: in your DetailsPage widget, is the fruit.id available correctly? any chance the value is null? If you could provide some runnable code I could help you out, and `Future<List<FruitDetails>> fetchDetails(int? a)` this future is returning a List of FruitDetails, should it return just a single `FruitDetails`?

Comment: @AJ989 Yes. If I use the id as title: Text() right after declaring return Scaffold and AppBar, it works correclty. That means the second page is receiving information from homepage. It's just the second fetch that isn't working.
About the runnable code, is there a way I can do it other than providing a github link? I'm new here, so yeah, noobs will be noobs

Comment: you can add an example into DartPad and share it here, https://dartpad.dev/

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, what you mentioned about returning a single ```FruitDetails``` is really pertinent. My ```Future``` function is returning a list of details instead of just one object with the details. I want just one object instead of a list. What's the better option to fix this? I've edited this post to show my parse functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
String newUrl = 'https://fruits.com/data/$a';
```

and make sure the value won't be null.

Comment: doing what you wrote for newUrl, or doing what he wrote, is the same thing, the result won't change.